# Direct voice interactions examples in use as an alternative to voice assistants

Tags: interaction-design, accessibility, conversational-interface, voice-control

After reading an article explaining the difference between using your voice to controlling the UI (i.e. [direct voice interaction](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/06/alternative-voice-ui-voice-assistants/)) compared to dealing with a voice UI (e.g. chatbots or voice assistants) to complete common tasks, I am wondering if this design pattern isn't already being used in more advanced applications like AR/VR or accessibility features in standard software applications.

As the author pointed out:

> Voice is a great modality for inputting information, but listening to
> a machine talking is not very inspiring. This is the big issue of
> voice assistants.
>
> The future of voice should therefore not be in conversations with a
> computer but in replacing tedious user tasks with the most natural way
> of communicating: speech. Direct voice interactions can be used to
> improve form filling experience in web or mobile applications, to
> create better search experiences, and to enable a more efficient way
> to control or navigate in an application.

Has anyone seen good examples of direct voice interactions in mainstream applications (other than the example provided in the article which appears to be their own project/product)?

Answer (score 1):

As for mainstream products that use them, YouTube has voice search on all devices, Google Search has it on mobile devices as well as embedded in Chrome's New Tab.

The game One Hand Clapping uses voice as an input for its puzzles.

I have not seen or noticed particularly many other uses of it though, certainly not on desktop.

Comment: Voice search feels more like input into the UI rather than controlling it. But I guess with AI models becoming more powerful and able to deal with language better, we might see some changes soon.